# how to use for loop inside a echo statement in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need Your help, 
I'm getting set of filenames using

```
for fn in "${fnames[@]}"
  do
   echo $fn;
 done
```

i need output like

```
const route=[{
     {name:'filename1',
      component:filename1,
      path:'/filename1'
  }]
```

I'm trying like this

```
echo 'const routes=[
      for i in '${fnames[@]}'
        do 
            echo '$i'
        done
]'
```

but it displays only one last element in the array
please give me suggestions I'm new to the shell script

Comment: you will need 3 echos. One for the 1st line, one for the last line. One inside a for loop in the middle.

Comment: Thnk you for your response .. I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple `echo` statements.

```
echo 'const routes = ['
for i in "${fnames[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
echo ']'
```